# Update manager won't install from un-authenticated sources

Tags: update-manager

My update manager shows updates available. When I click on install updates it shows the following and does not update.

> The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.

in details:

> accountsservice cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-ppdc empathy empathy-common libaccountsservice0 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsdriver1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 nautilus-sendto-empathy scribus-trunk

How to get updates ?

Comment: Welcome Sivamani , in terminal run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: @tijybba The same can be accomplished just by pressing "Check for updates" in the Update manager and then applying it. It also refreshes all package lists.

Answer (score 13):

To update from unauthenticated sources, use this command :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated
```

See the [Ubuntu manual page for apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/apt-get.8.html) to get more details about `--allow-unauthenticated` option

Answer (score 0):

You can un-check updates in Update Manager use this to find which update is causing the problem and then re-install the PPA it comes from.

Also try `sudo apt-get update` in a Terminal to update your software sources.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of updates is not too long and you want to upgrade just a specific item. You can also:

- Leave you update manager window open and go to synaptic,
- type in the name of the update needed from the update manager.
- If your update doesn't appear, remember to sort the search results by
  clicking the  ''installed version'' column header so that they appear
  at the top.
- Click on the relevant items with the grey exclamation mark then right
  click  and click mark for upgrade, then apply.
- A warning will come that the packages are unauthenticated. Click the
  button to continue the install and your update will be installed.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following 2 steps and check

1. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade --allow-unauthenticated`
2. Go to Update Manager --> click on settings --> select Ubuntu Software tab --> You can see an option "Download From" put the main server as the download location

Save it and run it, will works