# Authentication failure while updating

Tags: update-manager, authentication

[image]

After it downloaded the file, it reports an authentication failure and skips to the next task.

After finishing all downloads it reports that I should check my internet connection.

Just to make sure, I ran update-manager from terminal but still the same problem persisted.

Result of apt-get upgrade:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.01link.hk/pool/main/a/app-install-data-ubuntu/app-install-data_14.04.1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Failed to fetch http://ubuntu.01link.hk/pool/main/s/software-center/software-center_13.10-0ubuntu4.1_all.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Comment: you may have slow internet connection?

Comment: Everything else downloaded perfectly the only problem is with app-install-data and software-center. Also, it goes up till 100% then it shows the error.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, and post the results?

Comment: which os version u r using ?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Tumbleweed's post [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/93238/99908) pointed me to what went wrong. I changed the mirror to Main Server and it all worked fine!

[Anwar Shah's post](https://askubuntu.com/a/171148/99908)

I suppose even this can be done, but changing the mirror is a better and more permanent solution.